# css two divs side by side with textarea inside without using float or absolute

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs that are side by side and they have `display:inline-block` and they look great. I tried adding a `textarea` inside one of the divs, and it made it slide down so its not lined up next to the other div anymore.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/h0mwo9ox/3/) is what it looks like right now. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you please include your code? It would be helpful.

Comment: Best would be to create a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show the problem

Comment: this is expected ,they will display side by side and their bottoms will be lined up, is this what you mean https://jsfiddle.net/h0mwo9ox/

Comment: I think I know what's going on here but would need to see our code to confirm and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. Here is the code and a [link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL3khs8j/1/).

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    background: gray;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

textarea {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

I added vertical-align: top to your divs and textarea and set the width to 100%. I also set the border to 0 because it overflows by 2px.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `display:block` to the textarea and it sholud be fixed.

You can check it here -> https://jsfiddle.net/h0mwo9ox/4/

Quick suggestion, if you can, it is better to use specific classes instead of a generic div style, specially if your project became big it is better to manage then.

Comment: that doesn't fix it...